# I am getting segmentation fault after running Midori with x-org

Tags: archlinux, xorg, midori

I am trying to start midori like a web kiosk with ArchLinux.

I am getting an error after 1 minute:

(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x30

Fatal server error:
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting

(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 27 requests (26 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 523 requests (523 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
midori: xcb_io.c:528: _XAllocID: Assertion `ret != inval_id' failed.
xinit: connection to X server lost

What can be wrong?

My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
unclutter &
matchbox-window-manager &
while true; do
midori -e Fullscreen -a http://www.sabotagepkg.com/
done
```

When I try with www.google.com, it is working. Is it because of the memory? Or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running that script from?  It looks to me like you do this from within the X GUI.  In that case there is probably already a window manager running. Even if there is not and/or this is an xinit script, *you should not background the wm and go from there.*

The proper way to do this is to create a separate script with your `while true` loop in it and put the rest of the stuff in `~/.Xclients` or where ever is appropriate for arch (try there first):

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
unclutter &
whiletruemidoriscript.sh &
matchbox-window-manager
```

Now just "startx" from a VT (ie, with no X server running); this may be complicated if you boot to X, in which case just try rebooting.